# how to autofocus on new generated textbox by javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am generating a new text box on a button clicked in php program
HTML Code is written as

```
<table id="additional_item_numbers">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>&nbsp;Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-inps" size="50" name="additional_item_numbers[]" value="123" /></td><td>
<a class="delete_item_number" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
</td><tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am using this code to generate a new textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$("#additional_item_numbers").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#additional_item_numbers tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control form-inps" size="40" name="additional_item_numbers[]" value="" autofocus /></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
    }
});
</script>
```

This successfully generate a new input box at the exact point where it is required but it do not autofocus that new generated input textbox.
I want to autofocus that new generated textbox.
the keyword `autofocus` also does not work as I have already test that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
After I submit the form, a function is called on form submit by the following code

```
if ($this->input->post('additional_item_numbers') && is_array($this->input->post('additional_item_numbers')))
                {
                    $this->Additional_item_numbers->save($item_id, $this->input->post('additional_item_numbers'));
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->Additional_item_numbers->delete($item_id);
                }
```

Called function is a part of `class` named as `Additional_item_numbers` and is defined as

```
function save($item_id, $additional_item_numbers)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();

        $this->db->delete('additional_item_numbers', array('item_id' => $item_id));

        foreach($additional_item_numbers as $item_number)
        {
            if ($item_number!='')
            {
                $this->db->insert('additional_item_numbers', array('item_id' => $item_id, 'item_number' => $item_number));
            }
        }

        $this->db->trans_complete();

        return TRUE;
    }
```

But it adds the values in database only if the values are within 3 to 5 or upto 10...
If we add more than 10 additional Item Numbers. It doesn't add all values or sometimes add some of them.
Yesterday, We submitted 150 values but it added only 5 of them into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code .

```
$("#additional_item_numbers").find("input[type='text']").last().focus();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps :)
Another problem is, that my php program does not store all those fields values in the database, if the values are within 3 to 10 textbox values, then program render them successfully, but if the values are 10 or more than 10 it does not store all those values in database,
If you can help me regarding this! it would be great.

Comment: For sure sir! but I am new and it does not allow me, saying, at least 15 score is required to vote up!

Comment: Can you please provide me some information about that reason that why the program does not store more values in database ? if the values are within 3 to 10. it stores them but if they are more than 10... program doesn't store them into database.
While in php, there is foreach loop in array to store all the values in database

Comment: ok ... regarding your php issue can please share your php code in question

Comment: you insert each text box value separately in database or in single field ?

Comment: Sir I had added the details of php issue too. I shall be very thankful to you if you can help with this too...
A bundle of thanks for jquery help.

Comment: php code is looks ok as foreach loop takes all value submited values .. may be issue with database or you can print whole  $additional_item_numbers  and check all data submited data ...

Comment: is it possible to print a counter++ value in front of each input box added there ? It will help to know how much records we had entered. I tried with php, but it doesn't add counter++ because it is a server side language and the fields are added on client side.

Comment: why you want to print counter ? directly print_r($additional_item_numbers); and check how many values you get when submit form

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, But I want it to show on front end side where user is adding numbers so that he can see how much records he has already entered and which record number he is entering in current box. I had created an image for proper demonstration which you can see here.
[See the image for demonstration](http://homebusiness.net16.net/demonstration.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try following line after appending the html

```
$("#additional_item_numbers").find("input.form-inps").focus();
```

Comment: @Briesh Bhatt Thanks for your help... The above answer works so didn't check your code... but It is very value able for me that you answer me. Thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.(document ).ready(function (){
    $('#textbox_id').focus();
});
```